# Link to Lightbox Image-Group from Menu?

Tags: javascript, lightbox

Is it possible to link to the first element of a lightbox-group with data-rel attribute from the WP-Menu? I've tried serveral things (JinMenu Plugin, onclick function) but I failed. Do you have any clues for me? Maybe with Javascript? Or Plugin?

The links are formatted like this:

```
<a id="nomestart" class="mobx" href="http://www.testurl.at/testbild.jpg" data-rel="nomegroup"><img class="alignnone wp-image-1829" src="http://www.testurl.at/testbild.jpg"/></a>
```

Regards, David

Comment: Everything is possible if you're willing to put in the time. My immediate thought would be to do this with javascript/jquery.  Basically you'd want to append your navigation/menu `<ul>` with a link to the first item in the lightbox group by targeting it's `data-rel` attribute, then probably write a script to launch the lightbox?  Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks Tony Djukic, yes - i would like to launch the lightbox with target on the `data-rel` attribute, but without showing a picture twice in the group. there is a existing picture-group on the site-body and i would like to open the the first image of it, like i would click on it but from another clickable link in the menu. do you think that`s possible? i red a lot about onclick function, but maybe i put the script it not on the right place.

Heres a link to the site: [link]http://www.herwig-steiner1956l.at/artworks-3-index?passkey=hinterdiekulissen[/link]